# Cannot load and use synonym.txt file on ElasticSearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I am using the following docker-compose.yml to create an ElasticSearch cluster:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      ...
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ${PWD}/data/thesaurus/output:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/extra
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  elasticsearch2:
    ...
volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

My index contains:

```
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index" : {
      "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
              "synonym" : {
                  "type" : "synonym", 
                  "synonyms_path" : "extra/synonym.txt"
              }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
              "synonym" : {
                  "tokenizer" : "standard",
                  "filter" : ["lowercase", "synonym"] 
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

When I try to `PUT` my data, I get:

```py
{'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'failed to build synonyms'}], 'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'failed to build synonyms', 'caused_by': {'type': 'i_o_exception', 'reason': 'Is a directory'}}, 'status': 400}
```

Interestingly, when I run: `docker exec elasticsearch1 cat config/extra/synonym.txt`, I get the error: `cat: config/extra/synonym.txt: Is a directory`

How do I load and use the synonym.txt file?

Comment: I think my issue is due to WSL: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is an issue with WSL - see here: github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2151

As a workaround, I put my synonym.txt in a Windows directory and then linked to it, like this:

```
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - /c/QAMaker:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/extra
```

*NB.:* My Windows file system is mounted on both Docker for Windows and on my WSL distro on `/c`... I am not sure whether this would work if in my distro the Windows file system was mounted on the default `/mnt/c`

Answer (score 1):

As written in elastic documentation - [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html):

> The above configures a synonym filter, with a path of
>   analysis/synonym.txt (relative to the config location). The synonym
>   analyzer is then configured with the filter.

So you replace the `synonyms_path` :

```
"synonyms_path" : "/extra/synonym.txt"
```

in:

```
"synonyms_path" : "extra/synonym.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you but it still didn't work... See updated question.

Comment: try docker exec -it elasticsearch1 /bin/bash and then ls -al /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/extra/ what is the content of this folder? i think it's only a synonym.txt dir , right?

Comment: what is the content of ${PWD}/data/thesaurus/output outside docker? Here docker has created a synonym.txt folder?

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with WSL... Thank you for your help anyway.